# Accidently deleted dpkg/info

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I accidently did `rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/info/` and want to recover it.

Seemed only `dpkg -l` relates affected so far, which uses the indexed files to determine which package is installed but functionality was not harmed. I can still use crontab even if dpkg assume it's not installed, and do `apt-get upgrade` anyway...so do I really need to recover this? And how?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/484933/debian-removed-var-lib-dpkg-info-is-there-a-way-to-save-the-system

Comment: @user535733 I came up with an (almost) same solution, while some packages refused to be reinstaled, i.e. rsyslog. But it's another problem.